# How can I freeze a desktop then draw on it? Like gyazo or sharex region selection

Tags: python, user-interface

I am trying to make something like this, https://gyazo.com/b2dd4329487ee9f20fe8f731fe38bc9f ([This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMyDS.png)). I have no clue how to make the region selection (just the region selection). I am using kivy for the gui. This is what I have for the region selection/capture so far.

```py
import pynput
import time
import pyscreenshot

time.sleep(3)
print('start')

class ListenEvent:
    def __init__(self, pressed_x=0, pressed_y=0, released_x=0, released_y=0, ispressed=False, isreleased=False):
        self.pressed_x = pressed_x
        self.pressed_y = pressed_y
        self.released_x = released_x
        self.released_y = released_y
        self.is_pressed = ispressed
        self.is_released = isreleased

    def press(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed:
            self.is_pressed = True
            self.pressed_x = x
            self.pressed_y = y
            return

        self.is_released = True
        self.released_x = x
        self.released_y = y

event = ListenEvent()
listener = pynput.mouse.Listener(on_click=event.press).start()

counter = 1
while counter:
    if event.is_pressed:
        print('pressed:', event.pressed_x, event.pressed_y)
        event.is_pressed = False
    if event.is_released:
        print('released:', event.released_x, event.released_y)
        event.is_released = False
        counter = 0

im2 = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=(event.pressed_x, event.pressed_y, event.released_x, event.released_y)).save('im.png')
```

I basically need to "visualize" this code. I'd like to stick with kivy but I can use tkinter or any other gui libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageGrab
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from playsound import playsound
    from pynput.keyboard import Listener
    from io import BytesIO
    import win32clipboard
    from PIL import Image
    import os
    import random
    import threading
    import json
    
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    
    def read_json(file_name):
        with open(fr"{file_name}.json", "r") as f:
            datajs = json.load(f)
        return datajs
    
    def save_data(dataxl):
        with open("config.json", "w") as jsonFile:
            json.dump(dataxl, jsonFile)
    
    data_js = read_json('config')
    
    def random_char(y):
        str1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
        return ''.join(random.choice(str1) for _ in range(y))
    
    def takess():
        img_name = random_char(10)
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        img.save(f'./images/{img_name}.png')
        img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
        threading.Thread(target=lambda: playsound(rf'{cwd}\src\sound.mp3')).start()
    
        def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, datajk):
            win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
            win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
            win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, datajk)
            win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    
        image = Image.open(fr'./images/{img_name}.png')
    
        output = BytesIO()
        image.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
        data = output.getvalue()[14:]
        output.close()
    
        send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
    
        cv2.imshow('Captured Image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    class QuickSnip(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            root = Tk()
            self.setGeometry(0, 0, root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight())
            self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
            self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
            self.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
            QApplication.setOverrideCursor(
                QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
            )
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.show()
    
        def paintEvent(self, event):
            qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('dark blue'), 1))
            qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(128, 128, 255, 128))
            qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end))
    
        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            self.begin = event.pos()
            self.end = self.begin
            self.update()
    
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
            self.end = event.pos()
            self.update()
    
        def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
            self.close()
    
            img_name = random_char(10)
            x1 = min(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
            y1 = min(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
            x2 = max(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
            y2 = max(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
    
            img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
            img.save(fr'{cwd}\images\{img_name}.png')
            img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
            threading.Thread(target=lambda: playsound(rf'{cwd}\src\sound.mp3')).start()
    
            def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, datajk):
                win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
                win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
                win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, datajk)
                win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    
            image = Image.open(fr'{cwd}\images\{img_name}.png')
    
            output = BytesIO()
            image.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
            data = output.getvalue()[14:]
            output.close()
    
            send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
    
            cv2.imshow('Captured Image', img)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    def on_press(key):
        if str(key) == f"'{data_js['hotkey']}'" or str(key) == f"Key.{data_js['hotkey']}":
            app = QApplication([])
            window = QuickSnip()
            window.show()
            app.exec()
    
        elif str(key) == 'Key.print_screen':
            takess()
    
    def main_func():
        with Listener(
                on_press=on_press) as listener:
            listener.join()
```

make config json aswell